# How to find and plot the largest sample in a wav file

Tags: python, wav

[image]I wrote this code where I read a wav file and then It identifies where is the larger sample, but this only give me the possition of the max sample, but not the value of it, so what can I do to know which is its value? And when I plot it, why it doesn't fit on thw y-scale. For example, it says that the value is 6920, but when I plot, it only reaches 5535.
Thank you!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys


spf1 = wave.open('C:/Users/Martinez/Documents/Diego/Facultad/Proyecto Final/Mediciones Cubo/5 sentado/Lado 1_5 sentado.wav','r')

#Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
signal1 = spf1.readframes(-1)
signal1 = np.fromstring(signal1, 'Int16')

fs1 = spf1.getframerate()


#If Stereo
if spf1.getnchannels() == 2:
    print 'Just mono files'
    sys.exit(0)
print np.arange(signal1)
m = abs(signal1).max()

print m

Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal1)/float(fs), num=len(signal1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.vlines(Time[m:], [0], abs(signal1)[m:] )
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.axhline(color='black', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

won't `abs(signal1).max()` do the trick?

Comment: Hold on. You are saying that both `argmax` and `max` give you the position of the max element, and neither gives you the max element?

Comment: Sorry man, I was wrong about it, max actually gives me the right value, but can you see the update and tell me why it doesn't fit when I plot it?

Comment: I get a plot that looks reasonable.  What do you mean 'doesn't fit'

Comment: I uploaded an image to be more clear, the max value of my wav file is 6920, but as you can see, the graphic only reaches 5300 more or less. Do you know why is that?

Comment: 6920 is `m` which is the index, not the value.  I know this because `6920/44100 = 0.16`, which is where your plot starts on the graph.   Print `abs(signal1).max()`, and you should see 5355

Comment: It does the same because m = abs(signal1).max(), if I print abs(signal1).max() this print 6929 again! So what's wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40265/discussion-between-diego-martinez-giardini-and-ashelly)